# Boundedness of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Liouville's theorem says that if $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$, then $f\not=const\implies\not\exists M:|f|<M$. 
So, $|f|$ is unbounded. But can both $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$ be bounded below and unbounded above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the fact that if $f$ is entire, then so is $e^f$, $e^{-f}$, etc. What can you deduce about the absolute value of this new function? Try modifying this to address the imaginary part case.

*Edit*: I changed my answer to be less explicit, because I think it's worth calculating this oneself.

Comment: +1 Or: if $u>u_0$ then $f(z)-u_0$ is in the right half plane and then $z\mapsto \frac1{z+1}$ takes us bijectively to the - bounded - unit disk. In principle, we're using Riemann mapping theorem here, which sounds like too big a gun for this problem, but ultimately shows that nonconstant $f$ cannot avoid any unbounded connected closed set.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely a much more powerful approach, and can cover many more cases.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can tell about absolute value of $e^{\pm f}$ is that it's $>0$. But I fail to see how this could be used for imaginary part...

Comment: Let $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$ be the real/imaginary decomposition. Then $e^f = e^{u + iv}$, so $|e^f| = |e^{u(z)}|$. Can you see how to modify this now to use the imaginary part instead the real part?

Comment: I'd do $e^{-if}=e^{-iu+v}$, so $|e^{-if}|=|e^{v(z)}|$. But what does it give to my question? I seem to not follow your direction of thought.

Comment: Suppose $v(z) < M$, so bounded above. $|e^{-if}| = e^{v}$ is bounded both below by $0$ and above by $e^M$, so it is bounded, and hence $e^{-if}$ is constant by Liouville's theorem. But then $f$ must also be constant. And then you can do a further modification to check the bounded below case by using $-v$ instead of $v$.

Comment: OK, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $f(\Bbb C)$ is dense in $\Bbb C$. Indeed, if we miss $B(z_0,\delta)$, then $z\mapsto \frac 1{f(z)-z_0}$ is entire and bounded by $\frac 1\delta$ hence $f$ would be constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Can you cook up a bounded holomorphic function given that either of $\mathrm{Re} f$ or $\mathrm{Im} f$ are bounded below?